# Random Eclipse error on Windows 8.1?

Tags: eclipse, wsh

I usually use `Eclipse 4.4` for Android, although on this occasion I didn't have `Eclipse` open. I got this this random error message come up when I had no files/folders open or in view and not sure what caused it. Can someone help me figure out what caused this random error?

[image]